# date picker in partial views asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i used basic date picker in asp.net mvc and it works fine but now i converted my views in partial views at this time date is not working at all means nothing is displyed when i clicked in text box of date picker. the code that i have used is

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the method used for it is

```
         <script type="text/javascript">

                         $(document).ready(function() {
                             $("#txtTransationDate").datepicker();
                         });
                        </script>

                          <input id="txtTransationDate" name="txtTransationDate"    type="text" />
```

can you tell me how to display date picker in partial views. thanks.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date pickers are usually written in javascript in order to be more interactive and user friendly. Here's a nice [one based on jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger).